# Firebase Reads Suddenly Spiked with 54k

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am just getting my feet wet with firebase and in initial development, suddenly I get an error:

FirebaseError: Quota exceeded.

For context, I'm building a simple blog in React. It's saying the my function read problem is at "getPosts()":

```html
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { getDocs, collection } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { db } from '../firebase-config';
import './Home.css';

const Home = () => {
  const [postList, setPostList] = useState([]);
  const postCollectionRef = collection(db, 'posts');

  useEffect(() => {
    const getPosts = async () => {
      const data = await getDocs(postCollectionRef);
      setPostList(data.docs.map(doc => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
    };
    getPosts();
  });
  return (
    <div className="homePage">
      {postList.map(post => {
        return (
          <div className="post">
            <div className='postHeader'>
            <div className='post-title'><h1>{post.title}</h1></div>
            <div className='post-author'><h5>{post.author.name}</h5></div>
            </div>
            <div className='post-content'>{post.postText}</div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

So as I'm searching around the settings I find this graph that completely confounds me. Maybes someone can tell me what happened here.

[Graph showing reads spiking 54k at once.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28RE1.jpg)

Is mapping over the data this way accumulated 50k reads at once somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your useEffect doesn't have a dependency array, so it will fire indefinitely.
Add an empty dependency array at the end of your useEffect to only fire it on mount.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const { docs } = await getDocs(postCollectionRef);

      setPostList(docs.map(doc => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
    })();
  }, []);
```

Learn more about it [here](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/synchronizing-with-effects)